# Wix project template doesn't appear in VS2012 after installing it

Tags: windows, installation, wix, installshield

I have installed WiX 3.7 to create installer in VS 2012. But WiX project template is not coming in VS2012 Prof edition.

I have tried some resolution available in web, but no result.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The WiX project template (actually, a number of templates for MSI, MSM, custom action, etc.) are brought to VS by the WiX Toolset itself. If that's not the case for 3.7 version, you should file an issue: http://sourceforge.net/p/wix/bugs/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you refering in Wix Project template but there are template for EXE file and MSI file. and others.
here is my VS2012 + wix 3.7 photo. it's works great by the way.[image]

Comment: These do not appear to me either

Comment: you need to install wix 3.7 http://wixtoolset.org/ the plugin for visual studio 2012 comes with the installtion

Comment: I did, there is a problem preventing some users to get Wix 3.7 installed correctly :(

Comment: what do u mean a problem?

Comment: the templates do not appear after performing installation. Tried installing and uninstalling many time

Comment: oh well i guess you tried to restart the computer after that. so yes the wix forums are your help